# Stripe checkout session url not loading

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm getting a blank checkout page from the url object of the `stripe.checkout.sessions.create()` function in test mode. The stripe template is loading but no information is showing:

[image]

There are a couple of font errors in the console:
[image]

This is how I'm calling the Stripe API:

```js
let session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: 'subscription',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
        { price: priceId,
          quantity: 1,
        },
    ],
    success_url: baseUrl + '?status=success&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url: baseUrl + '?status=failed',
});
```

And this is how I'm setting the URL on the front end:

```js
let res2 = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify({
        intent: 'createPaymentSession', 
        priceId : priceId
    })
});
window.location = res2.url;
```

Comment: can you share how are you returning the session.url in the response?

Comment: I have the same / similar problem of a blank checkout page.

In my console I see an err msg of `Checkout URL is malformed` - it is the same exact URL as the one returned in the `checkout.session` object as returned by by the "create checkout session API".

Annoyingly, I have very similar code working just fine in another application - which (currently) leads me to think it may be something to do with how the Stripe test account is setup.

Answer (score 1):

```
success_url: baseUrl + '?status=success&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
```

This is not the complete url. There is an additional hash after the session id.

The correct url is placed in the response of the session create request `session.url`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same / similar problem of a blank checkout page when redirecting clients to a URL returned from the [create checkout session API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create). In addition, my JS console also printed the error message:

```
Checkout URL is malformed
```

After a helpful conversation with Stripe Support *(thanks Leo!)*, it turns out **Checkout URLs *may* contain characters that have already been percent encoded.** For example,

```
https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_xxx%2Fxxx
```

The issue in my case was that I was percent encoding the URL again before returning it to the browser, resulting in dodgy URLs like this:

```
https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_xxx%252Fxxx
```

Using the given URLs as strings verbatim and not trying to do any clever encoding myself, my checkouts are a lot happier!